# How to detect wether any button is clicked or not in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an iphone app i want that befor moving to next screen it should click on any of the 4 or five button i have and if user does not click on any button then it may not move to next screen

Firs two button from which user must click any one to move to next otherwise not

```
-(IBAction)locationOneButtonAction{

    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"radiogreen.png"];  
    UIImage *buttonImageOne=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiowhite.png"];

    [locationOneButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [locationOneButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [locationThreeButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [locationTwoButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [locationFourButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [locationFiveButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [locationSixButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    resturantLocation=@"Common Man - Bedford, MA";
}


-(IBAction)locationTwoButtonAction{

    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"radiogreen.png"];
    UIImage *buttonImageOne=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiowhite.png"];

    [locationOneButton setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [locationThreeButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [locationTwoButton  setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [locationFourButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [locationFiveButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [locationSixButton  setImage:buttonImageOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    resturantLocation=@"Common Man - Arlingtion, NY";
}
```

Next Button Move to the next Screen

```
-(IBAction)nextButton{

    FoodViewController*targetController=[[FoodViewController alloc]init];
    targetController.resturantLocation=resturantLocation;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Simple Way is to get a Flag..
in .h file Use a

```
BOOL _flag;
```

in `viewWillAppear` set it as `_flag = NO;`

On your each button's action which are mendatory to click before going on next screen set it `YES` like:

```
-(IBAction)locationOneButtonAction{
    // your stuff
    _flag = YES;
}
-(IBAction)locationTwoButtonAction{
    // your stuff
    _flag = YES;
}
```

In your next Button click use it like

```
-(IBAction)nextButton{

    if(_flag) {
        FoodViewController*targetController=[[FoodViewController alloc]init];
        targetController.resturantLocation=resturantLocation;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :) Let me know if you are looking for something else

Comment: i mean that like i have two button either of one should be clicked

Comment: Yes I got you. but let me know what you want if both buttons are clicked? And My solution will work if You click on both or any of one button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bool flag to identified if any of the button is clicked or not.If any of the button is clicked just make that bool flag true, otherwise initialize it to false and when user click next just check whether that bool flag is true or false.If it is false do not allow user to proceed.